# Distinguish between, for example, month February (02) and date 02 in pandas date column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am new to Python and I am working on a project where I work with timeseries data. I have a pandas dataframe containing the date of my dataset, a small example can be seen below (dates ranging for a whole year):

result_time: 2021-01-01 00:00:08, 2021-01-01 00:00:18, 2021-01-01 00:00:28...

I am processing this column in order to determine if the specific date is a weekday or not. When processing moves to the second day of January, i.e: 2021-02-01 12:07:17, 2021-02-01 12:07:27, 2021-02-01 12:07:37, and so on, the day part of the date (02) is considered as month February. I have tried to make it work but with no luck.

For example, I tried the following But nothing works. Please any advise will be much appreciated!

```
df_uci['result_time1'] = df_uci['result_time'].dt.strftime('%YYYY-%dd-%mm %HH:%mm:%ss')
df_uci['result_time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_uci['result_time1'])
df_uci['Weekday1'] = df_uci['result_time1'].dt.day_name()
```

Comment: I have never seen YYYY-DD-MM

Comment: From your question I cannot see where your problem is. Could you post the output of `df_uci.info()` to check the type of the column `'result_time'` and the errors or output of your code snippets? The code looks like it should be working, so I would guess the problem is some peculiarity in your data formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `pd.to_datetime()` function with the *format* attribute. Here you can define how your data should be interpreted. (Especially, it seems your day comes before your month)
In your case this should do it:

```
df_uci['result_time_as_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_uci['result_time'], format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")

df_uci['Weekday1'] = df_uci['result_time_as_datetime'].dt.day_name()
```